# How can I prove that the spectrum of the operator $A\in B(C(K))$ defined by $Af = g∙f$ is equal to $\text{Im}(g)$, for $g\in C(K)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, compact-operators, spectral-radius

I want to prove that $\sigma(A)$, the spectrum of the linear operator $A \in B(C(K))$ which is defined by $Af = g∙f$, is equal to $\text{Im}(g)$, for $g\in C(K)$. We may assume that $K$ is a compact topological (also metric) space and that $C(K)$ is the Banach space consisting of all continuous complex functions on $K$, with the supremum norm.

First of all, since the spectrum of $A$ is the following: $$\sigma(A)=\{\lambda \in\mathbb{C}:\nexists(\lambda I-A)^{-1}\},$$ that is, the set of complex numbers such that $\lambda I-A$ is NOT INVERTIBLE, which means it is not bijective (since we talk about operators)?? I have thought of analysing for which $\lambda$ it is not injective (non-trivial kernel, which means $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $A$), and same for surjective, but I don't know really how to do it.

Another way would be to analyse separately the point, continuous and residual spectrum of $A$ and take the union of them, but I  don't know how to distinguish them, since I am a beginner in functional analysis.

I really look forward to a reply. Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: There is no point spectrum if $g$ is non-constant. I would come up with a sequence of approximate multiplicative inverses for $g$ (staying away from $0$) and analyze the spectrum that way. You'd probably need Urysohn's lemma for that to ensure continuity. Bounded approximate identities (i.e. Dirac delta approximations) might work as well, similar idea as above.

Comment: Can you describe the operator $\lambda I-A$? What does it do to a function $f\in C(K)$?

Answer (score 1):

For $h\in C(K)$, define an operator $T_h\in B(C(K))$ by $T_h(f)=h\cdot f$. We claim that $T_h$ is invertible if and only if $f$ does not attain the value $0$. The "if" part is easy: if $f$ doesn't attain $0$, then $f$ is invertible and ${T_f}^{-1}=T_{f^{-1}}$. Now suppose that $\{x\in K: f(x)=0\}$ is non-empty. For any $\epsilon>0$ it is disjoint from the closed subset $\{x\in K: |f(x)|\geq \epsilon\}$ so by Urysohn's lemma we can find $f_{\epsilon}\in C(K)$ that is identically $1$ on the former, but vanishes on the latter. Then $\|f_\epsilon\|=1$, but $\|T_h(f_\epsilon)\|\leq \epsilon$. Letting $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ this shows that $T_h$ isn't bounded from below, hence cannot have a bounded inverse.

Applying this to your setting, we see that $\lambda I-A=T_{\lambda \cdot 1-g}$ is uninvertible if and only if $\lambda \cdot 1-g$ attains the value $0$, which happens if and only if $\lambda \in \text{Im}(g)$.